# RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER Visuak 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

he creado una aplicación que genera WCF, crea una instancia de visual studio y genera la solución automáticamente.

En visual Studio 2012 funciona perfectamente, el problema es cuando se instancia visual studio en su version 2015.

Si coloco puntos de interrupción por todos lados, genera todo correctamente, pero si lo inicio sin puntos de interrupción empieza a reventarse  y no siempre es en el mismo punto.

Arroja el error:

> " El filtro de mensaje indicó que la aplicación está ocupada. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))"

y no sé como solucionarlo.

Les dejo un pedazo de código. Generalmente se suele reventar en los for, momentos donde a a aplicación no le da tiempo a terminar otro subproceso.

```
bool exe = false;
            if (pathnametlb.ToUpper().Contains(".EXE"))
                exe = true;

            System.Type type = null;

            //Visual Studio 2015
            if (type == null)
                type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.14.0");

            ////visual studio 2013
            //if (type == null)
            //type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");

            //visual studio 2012
            //if (type == null)
            //    type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0");

            ////visual studio 2014
            //if (type == null)
            //    type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.13.0");            


            Object obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
            string nametlb = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathnametlb);
            string pathInicial = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathnametlb);
            EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte8Obj = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)obj;

            Solution4 solucion = (Solution4)dte8Obj.Solution;
            string nombresolucion = nametlb + "Service";
            string nombreProyecto = nametlb + "WCF";
            string newPrjectproxy = nombreProyecto + "Proxy";
            string csTemplatePath = "";
            bool existefuente = false;
            string sln = "";

            try
            {
                sln = pathInicial + @"\" + nombresolucion + @"\" + nombresolucion + ".sln";

                //Entra para modificar el sln con rutas Relativas
                Integration.ReemplazarRutasProyectos(sln);

                solucion.Open(sln);
                existefuente = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                solucion.Create(pathInicial + @"\" + nombresolucion, nombresolucion);
                csTemplatePath = solucion.GetProjectTemplate("ClassLibrary.zip", "CSharp");
                solucion.AddFromTemplate(csTemplatePath, pathInicial + @"\" + nombresolucion + @"\" + nombreProyecto, nombreProyecto, false);

                // solucion.SaveAs(nombreProyecto);
                solucion.SaveAs(nombresolucion);
            }


            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);

            //VSLangProj.VSProject vsPrj = (VSLangProj.VSProject)dte8Obj.Solution.Projects.Item(1).Object;
            VSLangProj.VSProjectItem vsPrjItem;

            var proyecto = dte8Obj.Solution.Projects.Item(1).ProjectItems.Item(1).Object;
            vsPrjItem = (VSLangProj.VSProjectItem)proyecto;

            VSLangProj.VSProject prjActual = null;

            foreach (Project item in dte8Obj.Solution.Projects)
            {
                VSLangProj.VSProject prj = (VSLangProj.VSProject)item.Object;

                if (prj != null)
                {
                    if (prj.Project.Name.Equals(nombreProyecto))
                    {
                        prjActual = prj;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sería útil incluir el error completo que recibes, incluyendo la pila de llamadas (stack trace).

Comment: Claro, este es el messague: "El filtro de mensaje indicó que la aplicación está ocupada. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))"}. y el stacktrace es este :   en EnvDTE80.DTE2.get_Solution()
   en ConvertDcom2WCF.Generador.CrearSolucion(String pathnametlb, String sistema) en C:\Users\omarP\Desktop\ConvertDcomToWCF\InfoDcom\Generador.cs:línea 92   pero como digo no siempre muere en la misma línea.

Comment: Ya veo. Si es posible, sería bueno que el código que compartes sea un [mcve] para ver si podemos reproducir el error que recibes.